# Row not deleting from the SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I m trying to delete the row from input for GoalWeight, Goal Date and Current Weight. It is not erroring but the row is not getting delete.

DeleteLayout

```
Button deleteB;
    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    EditText goalD;
    EditText goalW;
    EditText currentW;
    Intent j;
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.deletelayout);
        deleteB = findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        deleteB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goalD = findViewById(R.id.goaldinput2);
                goalW = findViewById(R.id.goalwinput3);
                currentW = findViewById(R.id.currentWinput2);
                if(goalD.length() !=0 && goalW.length() !=0 && currentW.length() !=0){
                    Toast.makeText(DeleteLayout.this,"Goal Date: " +goalD.getText().toString()+ "Goal Weight: " + goalW.getText().toString()+
                                    "Current Weight: " +currentW.getText().toString()+ " entered.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    myDB.deleteContent(goalD.getText().toString(), goalW.getText().toString(), currentW.getText().toString());

                    j = new Intent(DeleteLayout.this, historyActivity.class);
                    startActivity(j);



                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(DeleteLayout.this,"All data not entered.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Delete method in DatabaseHelper

```
public void deleteContent(String goalDate, String goalWeight,String currentWeight){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = " DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE GDATE = "+
                    goalDate + " AND " + "GWEIGHT = " + goalWeight + " AND " + "CWEIGHT = " + currentWeight  ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem (not the only one) is that inside `deleteContent()`, although you create the SQL statement, you never execute it by say `execSQL()`. 
So no attempt is made to delete any row.
However you should change so to use the [`delete()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D)) method, like this:

```
public int deleteContent(String goalDate, String goalWeight, String currentWeight){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String where = "GDATE = ? AND GWEIGHT = ? AND CWEIGHT = ?";
    int rows = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, where, new String[] {goalDate, goalWeight, currentWeight});
    db.close();
    return rows;
}
```

This is the recommended way, because it is safe and it also returns the number of rows affected/deleted (which you can examine to check if the deletion was successful).
So you can use it like this:

```
int rows = myDB.deleteContent(
        goalD.getText().toString(), 
        goalW.getText().toString(), 
        currentW.getText().toString()
);
```

and in the variable `rows` you will have the number of the deleted rows.